# Need to replace the list in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im trying to set the properties of userdetails that block of code is not working.

```
import CHATS from '../actions/ChatMessages';
import MESSAGES from '../actions/Messages';
import SEARCH from '../actions/SearchUser';

const chatReducer = (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case CHATS:
            return { ...state, ...payload };
        case SEARCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                userDetails: [...payload.userDetails]
            };
        case MESSAGES:
            let index = state.chats.findIndex(
                chat => chat.chatId === payload.chatId
            );
            if (index !== -1) {
                let conn = state.chats[index];
                const msg = payload.msg;
                conn.lastMsg = msg;
                const messages = [...conn.messages, payload];
                const newState = { ...state };
                newState.chats[index] = { ...conn, messages };
                console.log("state ", newState);
                return newState;
            }
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    };
};

export default chatReducer;
```

The userdetails field is not replacing the value. Any wrong with the state object ?

Comment: Share code for the user details field as well.

Comment: `userDetails: [
      {
        userId: 'dref6977',
        firstName: 'red',
        lastName: 'nine',
        phoneNumber: '720066077',
        createdDate: 1638080948597
      }
    ]
`
are you asking  this one ?

Comment: **The userdetails field is not replacing the value. Any wrong with the state object **

This one, can you share code for render logic, I expect a break there.

Comment: I just dispatched the action.
`render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-8">
                {this.chatSearch()}
                {this.chatWin()}
                {this.navBar()}
            </div>
        );
    }
` when i type somthing on the input field (chatSearch() function) it will call send websocket and will receive  onmessage. Here am dispatching the action type as SEARCH and updating the userDetails.

Comment: Oh I see, what if you state already has userDetails, that will be replaced by payload.userDetails instead.

Comment: You should use:
```
case SEARCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                userDetails: [...state.userDetails, ...payload.userDetails]
            };
``` instead.

Comment: No its not working. but other switch cases are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stuff works. After restart my IDE.

```
import CHATS from '../actions/ChatMessages';
import MESSAGES from '../actions/Messages';
import SEARCH from '../actions/SearchUser';

const chatReducer = (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case CHATS:
            payload.msgType = "";
            return { ...state, ...payload };
        case SEARCH:
        return { ...state, userDetails: [...payload.userDetails] };
        case MESSAGES:
            let index = state.chats.findIndex(
                chat => chat.chatId === payload.chatId
            );
            if (index !== -1) {
                let conn = state.chats[index];
                const msg = payload.msg;
                conn.lastMsg = msg;
                const messages = [...conn.messages, payload];
                const newState = { ...state };
                newState.chats[index] = { ...conn, messages };
                return newState;
            }
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    };
};

export default chatReducer;
```